# Can I use git or another versioning system to private repository on http hosting acount without ssh?

Tags: java, git, version-control, mercurial

I have 2 www/ftp accounts with php and sql in hosting companies but I haven't access to ssh. Can I install there any Version Control System like git or Mercurial? Or is any public free site to set up a private encoding developing repository?

Comment: Have a look at github - not free, but cheap.

Answer (score 5):

[BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org) is free, including for private repositories up to 5 users.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I install there any Version Control System like git or Mercurial?

Neither Git, Mercurial or any of the other mainstream VCSs are implemented in PHP, so you won't be able to implement them on your hosting account.  However, there are some possible alternatives that showed up in a quick Google search:

- [ASVCS](http://asvcs.com/)
- [IntraVersion](http://top-cat.com/intraversion.php)
- [phing](http://phing.info/trac/)
- [xinc](http://code.google.com/p/xinc/)
- [PHPVC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvc/)

I cannot comment on how good these VCSs are, what features they implement, how reliable or well-supported they are ... or even whether they are free.

> Or is any public free site to set up a private encoding developing repository?

There are a number of free public hosting sites for *open source* projects.  But I don't know if any of them offer free hosting for *private* projects.  (What is the "public good" in providing free hosting to a private project?)

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub](https://github.com/plans) is quite cheap for small users.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Codebase](http://www.codebasehq.com) to manage our projects and repository hosting (unlimited repositories, but there is a disk space allowance), with [Deploy](http://www.deployhq.com) to manage our deployments.  They've got a free plan on both applications.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [bettercodes.org](http://bettercodes.org/): they do offer some free private space.

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at [Perforce Helix Team Hub](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-teamhub/pricing). 1 - 5 users and 1GB / year is free.